# Haskell source file replace indentation with brackets

Tags: haskell, indentation, pretty-print

I'm trying to replace the use of indentation in a Haskell source file with explicit brackets and semicolons, while preserving whitespace and comments. For example, for the input

```
module Main where

   import System.IO

   f x = x

   main = print (f 5)
```

I expect

```
module Main where {

   import System.IO;

   f x = x;

   main = print (f 5)
}
```

I read in a paper that `haskell-src-exts` has a pretty printer but omit comments and whitespace; is there a way to use the library anyway, or some other technique I can use?

Comment: Have you looked for one at all?  SO is not the place to get someone to find you a library (hence why there's a close reason for that specific purpose).

Comment: @bheklilr I looked but couldn't find something out of box. I don't know Haskell and it's pretty hard for me to figure out how to use a library in Haskell. I read in a paper that haskell-src-exts has a pretty printer but omit comments and whitespace. So if I searched and couldn't find and don't know the language, am I allowed to ask a question on SO?

Comment: @Ali You should include all relevant details in the question. "I found this library but it doesn't quite do what I want/I can't figure it out; can I use it for my purposes" is a relevant detail.

Comment: Also, haskell-src-exts will do exactly what you want - for example, if your file is called test.hs, you could do `(fmap . fmap) (prettyPrintStyleMode style (defaultMode { layout = PPSemiColon})) (parseFile "test.hs")` (import the appropriate modules, of course). This information can be discovered quite easily by reading the documentation for haskell-src-exts; in the future, that is where you should start.

Comment: @user2407038: does haskell-src-exts preserve comments?